# Issue in running spring project in sts spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting the below warning in running spring boot application in sts spring tool suite

```
>WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/imart/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
>WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
>WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

My code is below.

```
package com.search;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App 
{
    @RequestMapping("/tools/related_info")

    public String index() {
        return "Hello How are you";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml as

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.indiamart</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>tools</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I m using java 11

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.0.x and Spring Framework 5.0.x are not supported on Java 11. If you want to use Java 11, you should upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1.x. This will also upgrade to Spring Framework 5.1.x.